# High performance Java object serialization on Google App Engine (GAE)

Tags: java, google-app-engine, serialization

We're looking for a high performance compact serialization solution for Java objects on GAE.

Native Java serialization doesn't perform all that well and it's terrible at compatibility i.e. it can't unserialize an old object if a field is added to the class or removed.

We tried Kryo which performs well in other environments and supports back compatibility when fields are added, but unfortunately the GAE SecurityManager slows it down terribly by adding a check to every method call in the recursion. I'm concerned that might be the issue with all serialization libraries.

Any ideas please? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Beware, premature optimisation is the root of all evil.

You should first try one of the standard solutions and then decide if it fits your performance requirements. I did test several serialization solutions on GAE (java serialisation, JSON, JSON+ZIP) and they were an order of magnitude faster than datastore access.

So if serialising data takes 10ms and writing it to datastore takes 100ms, there is very little added benefit in trying to optimise the 10ms.

Btw, did you try Jackson?

Also, all API calls on GAE are implemented as RPC calls to other servers, where payload is serialised as protobuf.

Comment: That only tells me you haven't been working with high performance system.

Comment: Thanks might try Jackson, but I'm assuming it will have the same issue of the security manager slowing it down

Answer (score 1):

Do you need cross-language ability? and re. high-performance are you referring to speed only, or including optimized memory management for less GC, or including serialized object size?

If you need cross-language I think Google's protobuf is a solution. However, it can hardly be called "high performance" because the UTF-8 strings created on Java side causes constant GCs.

In case the data you are supporting is mostly simple objects and you don't need composition, I would recommend you to write your own serialization layer (not kidding).

- Using an enum to index your fields so you can serialize fields that contains value only
- Create maps for primitive types using trove4j collections.
- Using cached ByteBuffer objects if you could predict size for most of your objects to be under a certain value.
- Using string dictionary to reduce string object re-creation and use cached StringBuilder during deserialization

That's what we did for our "high-performance" java serialization layer. Essentially we could achieve almost object-less serialization/de-serialization on a reasonably good timing.

Comment: Sorry but you get a -1. There are a lot of existing serialisation solutions in java and writing your own is a trait of inexperienced developer. Also, the OP should first do some testing and decide is serialisation optimisation makes sense.

Comment: Nah, if you really have looked at the existing serialization solutions in Java in detail, you would notice the various drawbacks of them. That's why I asked the OP in the first place i.e. what's the detail he's looking for. You might wonder why re-invent the wheel, but believe me in my industry people write their own serialization layer for a reason.

Comment: Thanks. I'm concerned mainly about speed.  I can zip it afterwards if necessary for size.  Don't need cross-language.  Strangely writing our own might not be such a bad idea in this case given the way security manager interacts with the libraries.